# Diagnose GE Fridge Electronics Issue

Tags: refrigerator

I have the following [GE Fridge](https://www.geapplianceparts.com/store/parts/assembly/PFSS5RKZASS) - it was made in 2010.
Last year the inverter went bad on it and it stopped cooling. At the time I had someone come by and put a new inverter in.

Recently - the LED lights on the door of the fridge as well as those inside began to dim and flicker (at the same time, seemingly in sync). Then the LED lights on the exterior (where it shows temperature of freezer and fridge) started cycling continuously (just shows "0 36" then goes blank and then does it again over and over). The fridge cooling capacity does not appear to be impacted, it is still very cool inside (same with the freezer). But the weird flickering seems to be getting worse? I heard it making a noise earlier, a clicking sound every 10 seconds or so it. That eventually stopped.

Is it safe to say this fridge is on its way out? Or does this sound like something I can salvage? Is there any risk of keeping the fridge on? (e.g., does this sound like a fire hazard?).

Comment: Most people are not good at judging temperatures. Get a thermometer that ranges 0 F - 60 F (more is fine, of course). Calibrate it with ice water (guaranteed 32 F at normal pressure). Then measure your *actual* fridge & freezer temps. If fridge > 40 or freezer > 20 (ideally should be close to 0) then you have real problems. Fire hazard? Probably not. Food hazard? Very much so.

Comment: Do you have a "Kill-a-Watt" home energy monitor ($20)?  Plug it into receptacles all over the house.  I'm fishing for one of two cases:  #1 some outlets too low, others too high, and this imbalance changes when you turn on a big 120V load (hair dryer).  #2 some outlets normal, others low, and things improve when you turn on a stove or dryer or a water heater cycles on.  If you find either one, smile because the repair is free and fast.

Comment: It sounds like the power supply that provides the DC for the controls may have a bad connection, broken wire or on its way out. Hard to tell if the wires are being routed through the pivot on the hinge I have had them short out there when the wire broke taking the controls out you might check that as a pain in the back side but cheap repair is possible.

Comment: My fridge developed a seizure-inducing interior light flash. I replaced the lighting board, and a few months later it recurred. I found a DIY solution involving the replacement of a fried resistor. Problem solved. My point is that the componentry in modern appliances are rock-bottom quality. You probably need a new control board of some sort, or a component replacement. Can't offer any specific help, though.